# How to detect if the Service(Web API) has lost connection to the HttpClient?

Tags: c#, httpclient, asp.net-web-api

Is there a good way to detect if the service has lost connection to the HTTP client of the current request being processed? My service is built on Web API in C#.

I have observed that the server keeps on waiting for 120 seconds before it raises following exception. Where can I configure this setting to wait less?
"System.Net.HttpListenerException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request"

thx

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Timeout` Property of the object you're using.

Check [this for `HttpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx).

Check [this for `HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.118).aspx).